# Distribute children elements or the top-level parent elements among monitoring hosts

Tags: distributed-computing, software-design, distributed-system

I've a monitoring system that periodically heartbeats compute resources assigned to my company's customers.

By default, each customer is assigned one physical server, but some of the bigger customers are assigned multiple physical servers.

The monitoring fleet has a bunch of servers running a monitoring software. As the number of customers with >1 physical servers are increasing, I am worried about uneven distribution of load, noisy neighbor problems etc.

However, I am unsure which of the following approaches I should adopt:

- Distribute individual servers among the monitoring hosts. As a result, servers assigned to single customer may be monitored by different hosts. Note that we don't save any server state in the RAM of the monitoring host, so this distribution will not affect the correctness of my monitoring logic.
- Distribute individual clusters among the monitoring hosts and use a load balancing algorithm with weight = size of clusters.

Any help is appreciated.

[Note: I am sorry if this is not the right place for this question]